# Can I study Quantum Computing or Quantum Mechanics with an Engineering background?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, quantum-computer

I am currently studying Electrical & Electronic Engineering. I wish to pursue Quantum Mechanics or Quantum Computing as my research subject. Is it possible for me to do my M.Tech. and then pursue my research subject? What are the prerequisites for studying these subjects? I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: You can learn anything you want, whenever you want. All it takes is spending time.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematical prerequisites for studying introductory Quantum Mechanics are basics in complex numbers, fourier analysis, differential equations and linear algebra. I think it is also necessary to have a grounding in Classical Mechanics. It would also help if you are comfortable working with probabilities at a basic level.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Your first step would be to learn Quantum mechanics from s standard textbook such as M[odern Quantum mechanics: by sakurai](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201539292), or [Principles of Quantum Mechanics: by Shankar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0306447908). There is nothing such as research in pure quantum mechanics, though there are a  small handful of people working on the foundations of quantum mechanics. If you want go to the the physics side of quantum mechanics, you could study [Quantum field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), or condensed matter theory. but it would ve very difficult for you to study these, unless you go through the whole physics undergrad curriculum starting from classical mechanics, statistical mechanics, electromagnetism and a great deal of math. If you want to pursue quantum computing it is not that difficult if you have some knowledge of theoretical computer science. Refer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32294/areas-of-computer-science-required-for-quantum-computing) for further information. After reading QM, you may pick up a standard textbook on quantum computing. Many universities will accwept PhD applications in these areas as long as you have the knowledge in these areas, though you should have sufficicient knowledge in Physics to crack exams like the GRE, or JEST, for PhD admissions.

Comment: I think with ur EE background, you would have the necessary mathematical background for studying QM.